# If multiple items are ordered they should have their own line item section

Tags: magento-1.9, array, json

**Here is my Code:-**

```
$orderIncrementId = "1000001";   
$orderCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order');
      $orderCollection->loadByIncrementId($orderIncrementId); 

   $order_data = $orderCollection->getAllVisibleItems();
   $json_data = $orderCollection->getData();

            $filtered_data = [];
            $names = $skus = $prices = $brand_names = $colors = $distributors = $distributor_skus = array();
            foreach ($order_data as $key) {
                $id = $key->getProductId();
                $productCollection = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($id);

                //echo "<pre>"; print_r($productCollection["name"]);
                $names[] =  $productCollection["name"];
                $skus[] =  $productCollection["sku"];
                $prices[] =  $productCollection["price"];
                $brand_names[] =  $productCollection["brand_name"];
                $colors[] =  $productCollection["color"];
                $distributors[] =  $productCollection["distributor"];
                $distributor_skus[] =  $productCollection["distributor_sku"];

                $name = implode(",",$names);
                $sku = implode(",",$skus);
                $price = implode(",",$prices);
                $brand_name = implode(",",$brand_names);
                $color = implode(",",$colors);
                $distributor = implode(",",$distributors);
                $distributor_sku = implode(",",$distributor_skus);

                    $json_data['name'] = $name;
                    $json_data['sku']=$sku;
                    $json_data['price']=$price;
                    $json_data['brand_name']=$brand_name;
                    $json_data['color']= $color;
                    $json_data['distributor']= $distributor;
                    $json_data['distributor_sku'] = $distributor_sku;

            }

       $item = $json_data;
       $filtered_data= array(
        array('order_info' => array(
            "entity_id" => $item["entity_id"],
            "state" => $item["state"],
            "status" => $item["status"],
            "is_virtual" => $item["is_virtual"],
            "grand_total" => $item["grand_total"],
            "subtotal" => $item["subtotal"],
            "tax_amount" => $item["tax_amount"],
            "billing_address_id" => $item["billing_address_id"],
            "email_sent" => $item["email_sent"],
            "subtotal_incl_tax" => $item["subtotal_incl_tax"],
            "total_due" => $item["total_due"],
            "increment_id" => $item["increment_id"],
            "order_currency_code" => $item["order_currency_code"],
            "remote_ip" => $item["remote_ip"],
            "created_at" => $item["created_at"],
            "updated_at" => $item["updated_at"],
            "total_item_count" => $item["total_item_count"])),
        array('line_items' => array(
            "name" => $item["name"],    
            "weight" => $item["weight"],                
            "sku" => $item["sku"],
            "price" => $item["price"],
            "quantity" => $item["total_qty_ordered"],
            "brand_name" => $item['brand_name'],
            "color" => $item["color"],
            "distributor_name" => $item["distributor"],
            "distributor_sku" => $item["distributor_sku"])),
        array('customer_info' => array(
            "customer_id" => $item["customer_id"],
            "customer_group_id" => $item["customer_group_id"],
            "customer_email" => $item["customer_email"],
            "customer_firstname" => $item["customer_firstname"],
            "customer_lastname" => $item["customer_lastname"],
            "customer_note" => $item["customer_note"],
            "customer_credit_amount" => $item["customer_credit_amount"])),
        array('shipping_info' => array(
            "shipping_description" => $item["shipping_description"],
            "shipping_amount" => $item["shipping_amount"],
            "shipping_tax_amount" => $item["shipping_tax_amount"],
            "shipping_address_id" => $item["shipping_address_id"],
            "shipping_method" => $item["shipping_method"],
            "shipping_incl_tax" => $item["shipping_incl_tax"]))           
        );


        echo json_encode($filtered_data);
        die;
```

**Output is:-**

```
    [
  {
    "order_info": {
      "entity_id": "455",
      "state": "new",
      "status": "quote",
      "is_virtual": "0",
      "grand_total": "4199.7000",
      "subtotal": "3792.9100",
      "tax_amount": "381.7900",
      "billing_address_id": "909",
      "email_sent": null,
      "subtotal_incl_tax": "4172.2000",
      "total_due": "4199.7000",
      "increment_id": "100000464",
      "order_currency_code": "AUD",
      "remote_ip": "122.177.51.43",
      "created_at": "2017-03-10 08:47:19",
      "updated_at": "2017-03-10 08:47:19",
      "total_item_count": "4"
    }
  },
  {
    "line_items": {
      "name": "Dell Professional Topload 14.1 inch Carry Case,DELL Latitude E7270 Black,Silver 2.4GHz 12.5\" 1366 x 768pixels i5-6300U,DELL Latitude E5470 Black 2.4GHz 14\" 1366 x 768pixels i5-6300U,Jabra BIZ 2300 Duo, USB, MS",
      "weight": "4.0000",
      "sku": "460-BBHF,N002L7270H12AU,N021L547014AU,2309-820-105",
      "price": "72.6000,1867.2800,1655.0300,0.0000",
      "quantity": "4.0000",
      "brand_name": "DELL,DELL,DELL,Jabra",
      "color": ",,,375",
      "distributor_name": ",,,distname",
      "distributor_sku": ",,,skutest"
    }
  },
  {
    "customer_info": {
      "customer_id": "73",
      "customer_group_id": "2",
      "customer_email": "kartik@excellencetechnologies.in",
      "customer_firstname": "Etech-Ngage",
      "customer_lastname": "Exce",
      "customer_note": null,
      "customer_credit_amount": null
    }
  },
  {
    "shipping_info": {
      "shipping_description": "NGage Shipping Fees (Shipping Costs for over 10 items will be calculated separately and appear on your invoice). - Table Rate",
      "shipping_amount": "25.0000",
      "shipping_tax_amount": "2.5000",
      "shipping_address_id": "910",
      "shipping_method": "tablerate_bestway",
      "shipping_incl_tax": "27.5000"
    }
  }
]
```

**But i want the Output like this:-**

```
[{
    "order_info": {
      "entity_id": "455",
      "state": "new",
      "status": "quote",
      "is_virtual": "0",
      "grand_total": "4199.7000",
      "subtotal": "3792.9100",
      "tax_amount": "381.7900",
      "billing_address_id": "909",
      "email_sent": null,
      "subtotal_incl_tax": "4172.2000",
      "total_due": "4199.7000",
      "increment_id": "100000464",
      "order_currency_code": "AUD",
      "remote_ip": "122.177.51.43",
      "created_at": "2017-03-10 08:47:19",
      "updated_at": "2017-03-10 08:47:19",
      "total_item_count": "4"
    }
  },
  {
    "line_items": 
        [
              {
                "name": "Product 1",
                "weight": "1.0000",
                "sku": "460-BBHF",
                "price": "72.6000",
                "quantity": "1.0000",
                "brand_name": "DELL",
                "color": null,
                "distributor_name": null,
                "distributor_sku": null
              },
              {
                "name": "Product 2",
                "weight": "1.0000",
                "sku": "N002L7270H12AU",
                "price": "1867.2800",
                "quantity": "1.0000",
                "brand_name": "DELL",
                "color": null,
                "distributor_name": null,
                "distributor_sku": null
              },
              {
                "name": "Product 3",
                "weight": "1.0000",
                "sku": "2309-820-105",
                "price": "0.0000",
                "quantity": "1.0000",
                "brand_name": "Jabra",
                "color": 375,
                "distributor_name": "distname",
                "distributor_sku": "skutest"
              }
          ]
  },
  {
    "customer_info": {
      "customer_id": "73",
      "customer_group_id": "2",
      "customer_email": "kartik@excellencetechnologies.in",
      "customer_firstname": "Etech-Ngage",
      "customer_lastname": "Exce",
      "customer_note": null,
      "customer_credit_amount": null
    }
  },
  {
    "shipping_info": {
      "shipping_description": "NGage Shipping Fees (Shipping Costs for over 10 items will be calculated separately and appear on your invoice). - Table Rate",
      "shipping_amount": "25.0000",
      "shipping_tax_amount": "2.5000",
      "shipping_address_id": "910",
      "shipping_method": "tablerate_bestway",
      "shipping_incl_tax": "27.5000"
    }
  }]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

find Updated code

```
$orderIncrementId = "1000001";   
$orderCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order');
$orderCollection->loadByIncrementId($orderIncrementId); 

$order_data = $orderCollection->getAllVisibleItems();
$json_data = $orderCollection->getData();

$_item=array();

$filtered_data = [];
$names = $skus = $prices = $brand_names = $colors = $distributors = $distributor_skus = array();
foreach ($order_data as $key) {

    $json_item=array();

    $id = $key->getProductId();
    $product = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($id);

    $json_item['name'] = $product->getName();
    $json_item['sku']=$product->getSku();
    $json_item['weight']=$product->getWeight();
    $json_item['price']=$product->getPrice();
    $json_itemjson_item['brand_name']=$product->getBrandName();
    $json_item['color']= $product->getColor();
    $json_item['distributor']= $product->getDistributor();
    $json_item['distributor_sku'] = $product->getDistributorSku();
    $json_item['quantity']= $key->getQty();

    $_item[] = $json_item;

}

$item = $json_data;
$filtered_data= array(

    array('order_info' => array(
        "entity_id" => $item["entity_id"],
        "state" => $item["state"],
        "status" => $item["status"],
        "is_virtual" => $item["is_virtual"],
        "grand_total" => $item["grand_total"],
        "subtotal" => $item["subtotal"],
        "tax_amount" => $item["tax_amount"],
        "billing_address_id" => $item["billing_address_id"],
        "email_sent" => $item["email_sent"],
        "subtotal_incl_tax" => $item["subtotal_incl_tax"],
        "total_due" => $item["total_due"],
        "increment_id" => $item["increment_id"],
        "order_currency_code" => $item["order_currency_code"],
        "remote_ip" => $item["remote_ip"],
        "created_at" => $item["created_at"],
        "updated_at" => $item["updated_at"],
        "total_item_count" => $item["total_item_count"])),

    array('line_items' => $_item),

    array('customer_info' => array(
        "customer_id" => $item["customer_id"],
        "customer_group_id" => $item["customer_group_id"],
        "customer_email" => $item["customer_email"],
        "customer_firstname" => $item["customer_firstname"],
        "customer_lastname" => $item["customer_lastname"],
        "customer_note" => $item["customer_note"],
        "customer_credit_amount" => $item["customer_credit_amount"])),

    array('shipping_info' => array(
        "shipping_description" => $item["shipping_description"],
        "shipping_amount" => $item["shipping_amount"],
        "shipping_tax_amount" => $item["shipping_tax_amount"],
        "shipping_address_id" => $item["shipping_address_id"],
        "shipping_method" => $item["shipping_method"],
        "shipping_incl_tax" => $item["shipping_incl_tax"]))           
);

echo json_encode($filtered_data);
die;
```

Comment: After re-reading it (a buch of times), I see what was going on and your answer is correct.

Comment: If you find this answer helpful then just upvote  so that it can be  helpful to other because I think post got unnecessarily down vote

Comment: @Gopal Patel first of all thanks for your reply.....your answer is right ...but i did not get the desired output. according to your code i got the order data 4 times with same info except (name, sku, price, brand name, color, distributor, distributor-sku).......so now i updated my QUESTION with full CODE, can u look at my code and tell me what can i do......plz help. i give u vote for ur reply.

Comment: Currently I am accessing through mobile. Will update you tomorrow @VishalThakur

Comment: @GopalPatel That downvote was me.  Edit your post and I'll remove it. Sorry.

Comment: @VishalThakur find updated code